# Convert Sql Schema to a JDL format

Tags: sql, postgresql, jhipster, jdl

I am searching how to convert my PostgreSQL data base schema to a jdl format. I used a project that I found on the internet which uses the jooq library: `https://github.com/Blackdread/sql-to-jdl`, but this one contains many errors and I couldn't run it.

Is there someone who know an other method how to convert a postgres schema to a a jdl file, and if jhipster provides a method to do so?

Comment: This is probably going to be hard or even impossible to do it automatically because your legacy schema may not follow JHipster's conventions for IDs, relationships and column naming..

Comment: i want to have as much informations as i can ... and for other changes i can do them manually ....

Comment: Then your best option is to contribute to sql-to-jdl by submitting fixes for issues you encountered.

Comment: is there an other solution for that .. for example convert liquibase xml files to a jdl ... ??

Comment: No as far as I know.

Comment: @Hana_CH Did you solve your issue? I was also using the sql-to-jdl tool but don't see how I could generate the JDL file. It seems to miss some classes. I can create the Java entities with JOOQ but this is not quite what I want. Thx